# Submitting pdf document in Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, iframe

I have a hidden submit form in a PDF document. I've managed to insert the form into an iframe on a PHP page. I've created a Submit button outside the iframe. Is there any way I can link those two buttons? I want to submit the form in the iframe when I click the submit button on the php page. How do I do this?

This is my `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/UniApp/results/fillsheet.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_DetailRS1['university_ID']; ?>" height="400px" width="750px" id="unipdf">
```

The `<src>` is referenced to this file fillsheet.php which code is:

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/pdf'); @readfile('fillsheet.pdf'); ?>
```

Comment: As far as i am aware this is not possible because it would be a security concern, at least not possible from the containing page.  You could do it via a browser plugin because plugins have a higher security level but this would probably not be good for your needs.

Comment: an alternate solution might be to build a page that automatically submits itself on load, then add the page via iframe dynamically when you click the submit button on the containing page.

Comment: @DallasCaley can you explain this further? Sample code may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

on the page that has the submit button (the containing page) add an iframe tag with no source like so:

```
<iframe id="iframeId" />
```

and also a hidden input to store the source:

```
<input type="hidden" id="iframeSource">http://localhost/UniApp/results/fillsheet.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_DetailRS1['university_ID']; ?></input>
```

on the page that the iframe loads add something like this (use the actual id of your form, or add one):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.('#iframeForm').submit();
});
```

then in the javascript for the containing page do this (assuming you are using jQuery):

```
var source = $.("#iframeSource").val();

$("#buttonContainingElementId").on("click", "#buttonId", function() {
    $.("#iframeId").attr("src", source);
});
```